# Glew in VS 2010: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit

Tags: visual-studio-2010, glew

I am learning OpenGL by following the Redbook.
When I come to around page 90, I need use `glGenBuffers()`;
Then I need to install "glew".

By following the steps in
here.

I download `glew.zip` from `glew.sourceforge.net/` and unpack the files.

I put

- `glew.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include`
- `glew32.lib` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib`, and
- `glew32.dll` in `C:\Windows\System32`

After that, I build my project in VS 2010 and in `Linker->input`, I add dependencies `glew32.lib`.

But when I build it, I have an error:

```
unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I need to compile the source code of glew.

How to compile it, see: [OpenGL: How to compile glew32.dll from source file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715530/opengl-how-to-compile-glew32-dll-from-source-file/4716857#4716857).

Then you will get `glew32d.dll` and `glew32d.lib`.

- Put `glew32d.dll` in `c:\windows\sysWOW64` (I also put it in `system` and `system32`).
- Put `glew32d.lib` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Lib`
- Put `glew.h` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Include`

Then it will work.

Comment: I spend two days to figure this out with the help from Hans Passant and Mark.

Comment: I had the same problem. I started again from the scratch with this manual and it worked: http://www.3dgraphicsfoundations.com/visstudio.html

Comment: @abimelex , thanks for posting the link, i had forgotten the step to define additional dependencies in VS, was driving me nuts

Answer (score 46):

Since it's not mentioned already, my problem was that I was linking against the static version of glew (glew32s.lib), but I hadn't defined the `GLEW_STATIC` preprocessor symbol (so the header I was compiling against effectively didn't match the library I was linking against).

Answer (score 6):

Another possible solution and less work than compiling the dll from source, is to just use the 32 bit binaries. Windows 7 64bit just doesn't want to co-operate with the 64 bit binaries that they currently have available.

Here's a pretty general setup guide if anyone needs. http://openglbook.com/setting-up-opengl-glew-and-freeglut-in-visual-c/

Comment: Broken link (404)

Answer (score 2):

I struggled with this too for a few hours. Then I realized my program is win32 instead of x64. I was including the glew.lib under the x64 folder when I should be using the glew.lib under the win32 folder.

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure you add the proper include for it. I did all the crazy library stuff and somehow forgot to actually include the header file.

In my case it was:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
```