# OpenGL: How to compile glew32.dll from source file

Tags: opengl, glew

I download the glew source file from http://glew.sourceforge.net/.
In the readme file, it says I should use \build\vc6.0\glew.dsw to comple the DLL.
But there are four projects after I open it in VS 2010.
When I compile them, 2 of them failed to compile.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a guess but by the way that folder is labelled, it's probably meant to compile using Visual C++ 6.0, which came with Visual Studio 6.  I just gave it a quick try and built without problems under that IDE.  Of course, I don't believe Microsoft offers that product anymore.  If you want to build it yourself, you'll probably have to upgrade the code base to Visual C++ 2010.

Comment: Could you tell me how to do that? Did you try the source code in VS 2010? Thanks. I am a rookie. So have a lot of dummy questions.

Comment: I opened the source in VS 2010. I think it converts to 2010 code. But there are some compile errors.

Answer (score 6):

Ok.
I figured it out.
Just open the the file in glew.dsw in VS 2010.
There are four projects.
Compile glew_shared, you will get glew32d.dll.
Compile glew_static, you will get glew32d.lib.

just ignore the other two.

glew32d.dll and glew32d.lib works fine in VS 2010.

This also answer my own question in

[Glew in VS 2010: unresolved external symbol __imp__glewInit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4711113/glew-in-vs-2010-unresolved-external-symbol-imp-glewinit)

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same problem. I converted the original project to Visual Studio 2010 and placed the result in https://github.com/chrisoei/glew. See the downloads section for a zip file containing glew32.dll built using VS 2010.