# Problems with Arcsynthesis OpenGL 3.3 tutorials

Tags: codeblocks, opengl-3

I was following OpenGL tutorials from this site - www.arcsynthesis.org/gltut/  and in the Building Tutorials section, i downloaded the 0.3.8 version of the tutorials. I extracted its contents in a folder in the desktop... I downloaded premake4, then I placed that in the folder where i have extracted the contents. Then I opened up cmd and I cd to the directory where I extracted the contents. Since, I'm using CodeBlocks, i typed premake4 gmake and then it started building stuff... I copied the contents of the framework folder to its respective directory. Then I went to Tut 01 Hello Triangle directory via command prompt and executed the premake4 command. After that, I opened up tut1.cpp with CodeBlocks and after compiling i get a number of these errors:

```
C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleCreateShader'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleShaderSource'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleCompileShader'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetShaderiv'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetShaderiv'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetShaderInfoLog'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleCreateProgram'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleAttachShader'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleLinkProgram'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetProgramiv'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetProgramiv'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGetProgramInfoLog'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleDetachShader'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleDeleteShader'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGenBuffers'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleBindBuffer'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleBufferData'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleBindBuffer'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleGenVertexArrays'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleBindVertexArray'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleClearColor'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleClear'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleUseProgram'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleBindBuffer'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleEnableVertexAttribArray'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleVertexAttribPointer'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleDrawArrays'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleDisableVertexAttribArray'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleUseProgram'

C:\Users\PB9X\Desktop\Tutorial 0.3.8\Tut 01 Hello Triangle\tut1.o:tut1.cpp|| undefined reference to `__gleViewport'

||=== Build finished: 30 errors, 0 warnings (0 minutes, 1 seconds) ===|
```

Where the hell did I go wrong? I already have GLEW, FreeGLUT, glimg, glload, glm, glmesh and gutil in its respective directories...

Comment: Looks like you haven't linked in GLEW: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/4711113/21475

Answer (score 1):

> Since, I'm using CodeBlocks, i typed premake4 gmake

Codeblocks, [as stated on the Premake4 site](http://industriousone.com/premake-quick-start), has it's own command: `premake4 codeblocks`. If you're using Codeblocks, you're supposed to use the Codeblocks build system, not try to juryrig the gmake makefile into Codeblocks.